# SUPEE 8788 fails on CE Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-8788

Ie've followed the instructions on the patch page as follows & still got an error message.

1) Downloaded the PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-38-31.sh for magento 1.9.1.0

2) chmod +x PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-38-31.sh

3)./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-38-31.sh

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form
/Gallery/Content.php
checking file    
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images
/Content/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
checking file    
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite
/Category/Tree.php
checking file   
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config
/Backend/Serialized.php
checking file  
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/
DashboardController.php
checking file 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 372 (offset -19 lines).
checking file  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/
UploaderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
checking file      
app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog
/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
checking file 
app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml
/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
checking file    
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/
Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
checking file    
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/
Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
checking file   
app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/
International.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file 
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/
Edit/Tab/Design.php
checking file 
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/
Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
checking file     
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/
MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
checking file 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/
product/helper/gallery.phtml
checking file    
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/
content/uploader.phtml
checking file 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/
product/edit/downloadable.phtml
checking file   
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/
product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
checking file 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/
product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
checking file    
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/
uploader.phtml
checking file  
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/
edit/tab/design.phtml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
checking file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
can't find file to patch at input line 5769
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|index 423902a..2c01684 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 5781
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|index caa979e..cd37804 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 5797
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|index d2a4937..c6c0221 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css 
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

Comment: try zipping patch in local, then upload to server, unzip there and apply patch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have applied all the patches successfully, Posted a separate answer in this question. please check if you want to Shyam Krishna Sreekumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have fixed the issue by our self by following steps on our Magento 1.9.1.0.

1) Change .htaccess & .htaccess.sample to default, if any custom configurations made on .htaccess.

2) If any one of the below patches was applied before SUPEE-8788, revert and apply the patches in above manner.

- SUPEE-5344 (PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh)
- SUPEE-5994 (PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46.sh)
- SUPEE-6237 (PATCH_SUPEE-6237_EE_1.14.2.0_v1-2015-06-18-05-24-23.sh)
- SUPEE-6285 (PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh)
- SUPEE-6482 (PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh)
- SUPEE-6788 (PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh)
- SUPEE-7405v1 (PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-42-03.sh)
- SUPEE-7405v1.1 (PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh)
- SUPEE-7616 (PATCH_SUPEE-7616_CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2016-01-20-03-08-56.sh)

Finally apply,

- SUPEE-8788 (PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-38-31.sh)

3) Apply your .htaccess rules after all the above steps & clear cache.

4) That's it. Now you can test your website on Mage report tool.

Comment: ok, all patches where pending. right?

Comment: Yeah. Please be ensure pending patches were installed correctly

Comment: I had lots of trouble patching via SSH - I took me ages to find https://github.com/magecomp/Magento-Pre-Patched-Files.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file at  lib/Unserialize/Parser.php and you will find its edited 
so Put original file of this file of same version and then try it again

Another alternative is you have to manually make those changes for that file from PATCH and remove that changes from PATCH file